# Jquery Tab panel to get focus on key press

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

I have a jquery tab panel. This panel contains some user controls like textboxes. My requirement is to set focus on tab when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. This is not happening. I have used the following code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tabs").keypress(function () {
            if (e.keyCode == 80 && e.keyCode == 18)
                $("#tabs").focus();
        });

        $("#tabs").focus(function () {
            if (e.keyCode == 37) {
                selected = (selected - 1);
                $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'selected');
            }
            if (e.keyCode == 39) {
                selected = (selected + 1);
                $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'selected');
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the keypress event on the document element instead of the tabs element? I had an issue similar to yours where keypresses wouldn't trigger because my element didn't have focus but switching it to the document fixed that issue.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you need to complicate it. 
Try this demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/417/

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('keydown', function (e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode;
        if ((keyCode == 84) & (e.shiftKey)) {
            $('.ui-state-active:visible:first').focus(); //ui-state-active is the class of active tab.
        }
    });
    $('#tabs').tabs();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try this:

```
inputs = $("table :input");
$(inputs).keypress(function(e){
      if (e.keyCode == 13){
          inputs[inputs.index(this)+1].focus();
      }
});
```

Comment: Why have you used table?

Comment: How is it related to the question? Can you elaborate it?

Answer (score 0):

first -> remove double qoutes .. they are used for components like input, p etc.
second -> try this code..

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#tabs').keypress(function () {
                if (e.keyCode == 80 && e.keyCode == 18)
                    $('#tabs').focus(); //  setting the focus
alert("working"); //test it
            });

            $('#tabs').focus(function () {
                if (e.keyCode == 37) {
                    selected = (selected - 1);
    $('#tabs').focus(); //  setting the focus
                    $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'selected');
                }
                if (e.keyCode == 39) {
                    selected = (selected + 1);
                    $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'selected');
                }
            });


        });


    </script>
```

Comment: $("#tabs").keydown(function (e) {    
  if (e.which == 9 && e.which == 16) {
  $("#tabs").html(this.value);        
  this.value = "";        
  $("#tabs").focus();
  e.preventDefault();
 }
});

Answer (score 0):

i guess might be work for u [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ParthAkbari/7Rfqa/32/)

**js**

```
$("#status").keydown(function (e) {    
  if (e.which == 9) {
  $("#statuses").html(this.value);        
  this.value = "";        
  $("#status").focus();
  e.preventDefault();
 }
});
```

Comment: Its not letting the focus to go